# Símbolos balanceados

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un programa que me muestre si una secuencia de caracteres (`"()","{}","[]"`) están balanceados o no, en mi código el primer número corresponde al número de casos o secuencias que quiero analizar y los `";"` indican hasta donde llega cada secuencia, el problema es que no me muestra lo que debería y me sigue indicando que ingrese más caracteres, como ejemplo ingreso: 3 `{ [ ( ) ] } ; [ ] { } ( ) ; ( ) { [ } ] ;` y me debería de mostrar: `correcta correcta incorrecta`

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Deque<String> pila = new LinkedList<String>();
    int casos;
    String simbolo;

    casos = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < casos; i++) {
        while (true) {
            simbolo = in.next();
            if (simbolo.equals("(") || simbolo.equals("[") || simbolo.equals("{")) {
                pila.addFirst(simbolo);
            }
            if (simbolo.equals(")") || simbolo.equals("]") || simbolo.equals("}")) {
                pila.pollFirst();
            }
            if (simbolo.equals(";")) {

                if (pila.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("correcta");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("incorrecta");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué `while (true)`? Así como está, nunca sale de ese _loop_...

Comment: Podrias aclarar que es lo que muestras? si en algun momento encontras una incorrecta, no deberias limpiar la pila?

Comment: balanceado quiere decir que el numero de simboles que "abren" sean igual al número de símbolos que "cierran" y eso es lo que hace tu programa por eso la tercera expresión siempre es correcta

Comment: No estas comprobando que los símbolos sean los correctos. Por ejemplo un `{` no se cierra con un `]`, al sacar de la pila deberías comprobar el símbolo.